# pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'tuple'>

Tags: pytorch

Im trying to download cifar10 images and put it in dataloader, however the problem
'**pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'tuple'>**' keeps occur. Please help me.

```
transform_list={'train':transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                                           transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                           transforms.FiveCrop(size=224),
                                           transforms.ToTensor(),
                                           transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5,0.5,0.5), std=(0.5,0.5,0.5))]),
               'test':transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224),
                                          transforms.ToTensor(),
                                          transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5,0.5,0.5), std=(0.5,0.5,0.5))])}
    cifar10_train=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data',train=True,download=True,transform=transform_list['train'])
    cifar10_test=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data',train=False,download=True,transform=transform_list['test'])
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(cifar10_train, batch_size=128,
                                             shuffle=True)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(cifar10_test, batch_size=128,
                                             shuffle=True)
    
    print(cifar10_train)
    print(cifar10_train[0])
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-03a0afd731d1> in <module>()
     15 
     16 print(cifar10_train)
---> 17 print(cifar10_train[0])

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py in to_tensor(pic)
    100     """
    101     if not(F_pil._is_pil_image(pic) or _is_numpy(pic)):
--> 102         raise TypeError('pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got {}'.format(type(pic)))
    103 
    104     if _is_numpy(pic) and not _is_numpy_image(pic):

TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error is using `FiveCrop()`. Because it gives a tuple of image array.
To solve this problem use `Lambda` to normalize each element of the tuple. Try this snippet to solve the problem:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Resize((256, 256)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.FiveCrop((224, 224)),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda crops: torch.stack([transforms.Normalize(mean, std)(crop) for crop in crops]))    
])
```